# classList Changes to an Element are only there during the duration of an iteration

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, sapui5

with `classList.add` - Method I added new color to bunch of Elements within my page, however the changes are only there during the iteration of the Loop.

```css
.Color {
  color: yellow !important;
}
```

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var id = this.byId("TableName").getItems()[i].Id;

  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.classList.add("Color");
}
```

Expected: 5 Elements will get its color changed to yellow permanently.

Actual: 5 Elements got it color changed to yellow but only for the duration of a Loop, i.e |i| = 5.

Comment: When the color changed back (After the iteration) is the class `.color` still there? Or some process removes it?

Comment: Its still there

Comment: What are those _5 elements_? `sap.m.Text`? And what does yellow mean semantically? Warning? Or just highlighting?

Comment: So, the other option is that some other css rule overrides the style. Can you check what it is (in the style panel in dev tools) https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/

Comment: @Roman _> but only for the duration of a Loop_ ... How can the browser apply the color during the loop anyway if the loop is running synchronously? Something must be happening after the loop. Maybe `.invalidate()`?

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann, i cant fully tell what it is, however is done in Sap ui5 web ide, thereby sap.m.Text, might be the answer, also .sapMListTbl .sapMText, .sapMListTbl .sapMLabel, all give out an color, which during the time of the Loop will be Overwritten by the class Color, however after the Loop, class Color seems to disappear. About the Loop: with debugger its possible to run every iteration of the loop with stop, ie i= 0 loop goes to 1 shows the results -> you press go one more time, goes to 2 and so on.

Comment: What's the purpose of changing the color of the table rows? In SAPUI5 there are other methods to set a class. If you use jQuery this will update the DOM directly but a rerender (caused by a property change) will make SAPUI5 "redraw" the control again back to standard (loosing your color css).